# anacron cron.weekly only runs when logged in

Tags: login, anacron

I have a weekly cron job set up to run every Saturday morning at 00:01 AM.  The anacron.weekly entry in the crontab is set to run at Saturdays at 00:01 AM crontab entry is:

```
1 0 * * 6 root  test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
```

The anacrontab has a a weekly entry set up as:

```
7 10 cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
```

The script is contained in the `/etc/cron.weekly` directory, owned by root, with execute permissions

The problem is that the job does not run when I am NOT logged in as root, but as soon as I log in as root, the cron job will run perfectly (after the 10 min anacron delay)
 and do exactly what it is supposed to do.

The job does exhibit the desired behavior of once it runs, it won't run again until after the next weekly job is supposed to run, but then only after I log in.  i.e. If I log in on Friday night it won't run but if I log in on Saturday night it will and then wont' run again until after 00:01 the next Saturday.

My filesystem nor my home directory are encrypted.  The job is owned by root and only runs when I log in as root.  Once the job runs, it is logged in the `/var/log/syslog`, and the `/var/spool/anacron/cron.weekly` file is set to the date the job ran. All log files created by the job are created and show a successful completion.

I have verified that the server is up at the time the job is supposed to run.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the name of the script? This really sounds fishy :-(

Comment: The script is a script I created, mediaback no extensions.  It creates archives of all my movies, pictures and music.  The script doesn't seem to be the problem since it runs perfectly after I log in.  Here is the listing from the /etc/cron.weekly directory.

Comment: Got caught by the edit timer:@Rinzwind Thanks for the reply, the script is a script I created, mediaback no extensions.  It creates archives of all my movies, pictures and music.  The script doesn't seem to be the problem since it runs perfectly after I log in.  Here is the listing from the /etc/cron.weekly directory.           `-rw-r--r--   1 root root   102 Feb  9  2013 .placeholder
>-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   312 Feb 19  2014 0anacron
>-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4293 Feb 21 10:24 mediaback`

Comment: Are you logging in as `root`, or logging in as `user` and becoming `root`? Try this cron job both when you are logged in and not: `(date;mount;pwd;echo $PATH;id) >>/tmp/logfile` and check for differences.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are actually running `anacron` regularly and not just when logged in as root. The line you posted from your crontab tests if `anacron` is executable and *if it isn't* will run your weekly scripts Saturdays at 00:01 AM—in particular, it does not run `anacron` even if present and executable.

`anacron` needs regular opportunities to run, and each time will check and run any tasks that have come due. On my system (Arch, not Ubuntu), `cron` runs `anacron` hourly via a `0anacron` script in `/etc/cron.hourly`.